# ActiveMQ Artemis configuration in AWS problem

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, activemq-artemis

I am trying to connect an ActiveMQ Artemis broker on a publicly accessible server outside of the AWS cloud to an Artemis broker in AWS.

The AWS side has a [Route 53](https://aws.amazon.com/route53/) entry and a [classic load balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/introduction.html) to route the incoming request to Artemis running on an EC2 instance. Both brokers are using a CORE bridge to connect with each other. I am using the Netty SSL protocol and trying to use certificates.

Neither side is able to connect its "bridge" to the other. Using the nice Route 53 name I am able to ping that from the public server outside of AWS. Artemis is not able to connect from the AWS EC2 to the public instance - not sure if that is also related to the NAT or Internet gateway on my VPC. But, the NAT and IGW look correct and AWS security groups look correct.

**Questions:**

- Would Route53 and a classic ELB work to route message requests to Artemis?
- What values should be used as the IP/server name and port in the Connector and Acceptor?
- Has anyone done this? I find no other references out there.

Yes, I know of "AWS ActiveMQ" service. That is a backup plan.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It might help to simplify the configuration a bit. What happens if you don't use SSL? Can you provide the `broker.xml` for both brokers?

Comment: Also, what (if any) error messages do you see in either log?

Comment: I removed all certificates and made the connection plain TCP --- DEBUG [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.cluster.impl.BridgeImpl] 
Underlying bridge connection failure: ActiveMQNotConnectedException[errorType=NOT_CONNECTED message=AMQ219007: 
Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.]
 at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:799) [artemis-core-client-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]

Comment: You should add the requested details to the original question rather than in the comments.

Comment: BTW, that `DEBUG` message would be considered "normal" in the case where the bridge couldn't connect to its target. It sounds to me like there's just something wrong in the environment or perhaps your configuration is wrong given the different network layers the TCP connection must pass through.